# how to prove that this function is integrable??

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}{x^2y + y^3}&\text{0 ≤ x ≤ 1, 0 ≤ y ≤ 1}& \\x^3y + x & \text{1 < x ≤ 2, 0 ≤ y ≤ 1}& \end{cases}$

How to prove that f is integrable over ${0\leq x\leq 2, 0 \leq y\leq 1}$ and how to integrate it later?

It gives me the idea that it is a step function with a single discontinuity, so how to check that the set of discontinuities has zero content?

Comment: The set of discontinuities is included in a straight line, hence. ..

Answer (score 0):

What knowledge can be assumed? I would suffice it to say that since $f(x,y)$ is piecewise continuous on $\Omega = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2} : 0\leq x\leq2,0\leq y\leq1\}$ and since piecewise continuous functions are integrable then $f$ is integrable on $\Omega.$

This can of course be proven. If you want to see a proof for the case where $f:D\subseteq \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ then [I found a decent one here via a quick google search](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/resource/general/131ah.1.03w/week9.pdf) (see page 18-19).

Assuming the integral you want to compute is $$\int_0^1 \int_0^2 f(x,y)dxdy$$ then you may separate it as

$$\int_0^1 \bigg(\int_0^2 f(x,y)dx\bigg)dy = \int_0^1 \bigg(\int_0^1 x^2y + y^3dx+\int_1^2 x^3y+xdx\bigg)dy$$